# \DeclareSymbolFont undesired effect

Tags: fonts, math-operators

I would like to have math operator names in Sans Serif.
`\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}` does the job but has also an effect on Greek capitals.
How do I change font for operator names keeping the rest of the formatting intact?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you meaning operators such as sine, cosine and logarithm?

Comment: @egreg Yes, those and custom defined with `\operatorname` or `\DeclareMathOperator`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your aim is to change the typesetting of operator names to use sans serif type, you should define a new symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% a new symbol font for names of operators
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
% don't waste a math group
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfoperators}
% tell LaTeX to use sfoperators for names of operators
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}

$\sin\Gamma+\log(x-\Phi)-\foo(y)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What do I do, if I want to be able to define operators using different fonts within one document? This is a theoretical question at this point, but for the future reference...

Comment: @SlavaMatveev `\DeclareMathOperator{\baz}{\mathbf{baz}}` works.

Comment: Sorry for pestering... What does this `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfoperators}` do?