# Switch math font to sans serif in caption

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, sans-serif

I use [the opentype version of Alegreya](https://github.com/huertatipografica/Alegreya/tree/master/fonts) for the main text including math and [the opentype version of Alegreya Sans](https://github.com/huertatipografica/Alegreya-Sans/tree/master/fonts) for headings and captions. Sometimes I have some math in captions of figures and tables, which I would like to have in the sans serife font, too. I know that I can declare a sans-version with `unicode-math` which can be used with `symsf{...}`, etc. But since some of my math is "hidden" in commands for chemical compounds, this is quite a bad option for me. So I tried to define two math commands and add them to `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily`. The following MWE works for me:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    %Path={Alegreya/},% add appropriate directory
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{Alegreya}

\setsansfont[
    %Path={AlegreyaSans/},% add appropriate directory
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{AlegreyaSans}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\newcommand{\rmmath}{
    \setmathfont{Alegreya-Regular.otf}[Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
    \setmathfont{Alegreya-Italic.otf}[range=it/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
    \setmathfont{Alegreya-Regular.otf}[range=up/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num,},Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
    \setmathfont{Alegreya-BoldItalic.otf}[range=bfit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
    \setmathfont{Alegreya-Bold.otf}[range=bfup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
}

\newcommand{\sfmath}{
    \setmathfont{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}[Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
    \setmathfont{AlegreyaSans-Italic.otf}[range=it/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
    \setmathfont{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}[range=up/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num,},Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
    \setmathfont{AlegreyaSans-BoldItalic.otf}[range=bfit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
    \setmathfont{AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}[range=bfup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num},Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]
}

\xapptocmd{\rmfamily}{\rmmath}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\sffamily}{\sfmath}{}{}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}

\begin{document}
\rmfamily
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound\\    
\sffamily
Text in sf with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound    
\end{document}
```

The problem arises when I use the switch more than once. So this...

```
\begin{document}
\rmfamily
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound\\
\sffamily
Text in sf with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound\\
\rmfamily% ---> fails at this point (! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.)
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound
\end{document}
```

... and this ...

```
\begin{document}
\rmfamily
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound\\
\sffamily
Text in sf with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \compound\\
\begin{figure}
%   \caption{Figure.}% ---> fails at this point (! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.)
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

... or just this ...

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure.}% ---> fails at this point (! LaTeX Error: Symbol font `__um_fam1' not defined.)
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

... all fail with the errors given in the code. This behavior was [already mentioned some months ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398895/using-two-different-math-fonts-with-lualatex).

Other solutions suggest [to use `mathversion` with `unicode-math`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128887/switching-math-fonts-with-unicode-math). But this lacks the `range=` argument which I need for italic variables and upright numbers. I also gave `sansmath`-package a trial but could not get it to work with my fonts.

I wonder if there is really no workaround or solution for the `unicode-math` issue. I would appreciate if somebody had some suggestions for this or maybe for a complete different solution which I am not aware of.

PS: I would prefer a XeLaTeX solution, since LuaLaTeX is extremely slow on my system.

Answer (score 4):

**A**

With markup in the caption text, specifically, `\symsf{}`:

Firstly, `\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}` without `\symsf`.

[image: serif math in caption]

Colour-coding shows the math component is serif; the rest is caption text, in sf style.

Sans version, using `\symsf{}`:

[image: sans-serif]

but very fiddly in terms of code:

`\ch{A_{$\symsf{x}$}B_{$\symsf{x}-\symsf{1}$} * $\symsf{n}$ H2O}`

(`unicode-math` documentation: 5.1 Math 'style', p 12: "If glyphs are desired that do not map as per the package option [for font style], markup is required")

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}%[Colour=red]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Serif}[range=up/{Latin,Greek,num},Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Noto Serif Italic}[range=it/{latin,greek},Colour=red]

%\setmathfontface\capmath{Asana Math}[Colour=violet]

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}
\newcommand{\compoundb}{\ch{A_{$\symsf{x}$}B_{$\symsf{x}-\symsf{1}$} * $\symsf{n}$ H2O}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\rmfamily
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.

\sffamily
\noindent Text in sf with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.

\ttfamily
\noindent Text in tt with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx
\end{center}
\caption{\compound}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx
\end{center}
\caption{\compoundb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**B**

Alternatively, putting the whole `\ch` in math mode instead, and using `\mathsf` seems to work:

[image: with mathsf]

`$\mathsf{\ch{A_{x}B_{x-1} * n H2O}}$`

"Seems" is the keyword: `$\mathit{\ch{A_{x}B_{x-1} * n H2O}}$` produces the same result.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}%[Colour=red]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Serif}[range=up/{Latin,Greek,num},Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Noto Serif Italic}[range=it/{latin,greek},Colour=red]

%\setmathfontface\capmath{Asana Math}[Colour=violet]

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}
\newcommand{\compoundb}{\ch{A_{$\symsf{x}$}B_{$\symsf{x}-\symsf{1}$} * $\symsf{n}$ H2O}}
\newcommand{\compoundc}{$\mathsf{\ch{A_{x}B_{x-1} * n H2O}}$}


\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\rmfamily
Text in rm with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.

\sffamily
\noindent Text in sf with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.

\ttfamily
\noindent Text in tt with math $3a + b_2 = c - \alpha\times x \frac{3}{4}$ and chemical formula \mbox{\compound}.


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx
\end{center}
\caption{\compound}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx with \textbackslash mathsf
\end{center}
\caption{\compoundc}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**C**

For this particular `\ch`, no-math mode also "works", with results the same as (B).

`\ch{A_{x}B_{x-1} * n H2O}`

**Conclusion**

Depending on the `ch`, a math mode solution might not be required at all.

The `\captionsetup{textfont={sf}}` must be taking place later in the processing, or overriding things, but before the `sym..{}` substitutions take place.

This is with `\symbf`:

[image: symbf]

=====

**Addendum**

The workarounds

The hurdle is that it seems that math and text cannot be truly escaped (yet) inside `chemformula` package's `\ch` command (`chemformula.sty`, line 3568, version 4.15 (2017)).

So the workaround will be manual markup.

There are several ways of doing so.

Given that two fonts have to intersect

[image: intersecting fonts]

math sans upright (sfup) - marked in red in the image - and text sffamily - marked in blue -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=blue]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Sans}[range=sfup/{latin,greek,num},Colour=red]

\usepackage{chemformula}%3.3 own manual; separate from chemmacros since Jul-2013
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}
\newcommand{\compoundsfup}{\ch{A_{$\symsfup{x}$}B_{$\symsfup{x}-\symsfup{1}$} * $\symsfup{n}$ H2O}}


\begin{document}

Inline text with \compound .
\vspace{24pt}

\begin{tabular}{l|ll}
Text & $\symsfup{symsfup}$ & normal \\
\hline \\
\rmfamily rmfamily & \rmfamily\compoundsfup & \rmfamily\compound \\
\sffamily sffamily & \sffamily\compoundsfup & \sffamily\compound\\
\ttfamily ttfamily & \ttfamily\compoundsfup & \ttfamily\compound \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

markup can be done totally manually, but is time-consuming, and two separate markups have to be maintained:

**Method 1**

[image: manual markup]

`\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}`

and

`\newcommand{\compoundsfup}{\ch{A_{$\symsfup{x}$}B_{$\symsfup{x}-\symsfup{1}$} * $\symsfup{n}$ H2O}}`

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=blue]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Sans}[range=sfup/{latin,greek,num},Colour=red]

\usepackage{chemformula}%3.3 own manual Jul-2013
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand{\compound}{\ch{A_{$x$}B_{$x-1$} * $n$ H2O}}
\newcommand{\compoundsfup}{\ch{A_{$\symsfup{x}$}B_{$\symsfup{x}-\symsfup{1}$} * $\symsfup{n}$ H2O}}

\begin{document}

Inline text with \compound .


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx 
\end{center}
\caption{\compoundsfup}
\end{figure}

Two separate markups.



\end{document}
```

**Method 2**

Slightly more efficient is parsing twice from the source code text, using regex to automatically replace anything between `$...$` with `symbfup` in one case and `symrm` in the other:

[image: parsed markup]

The regex is: `\$([^\$]+)\$` = one or more of anything after a `$`, that is not a `$`, up to the next `$`, treated as a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=blue]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Sans}[range=sfup/{latin,greek,num},Colour=red]

\usepackage{chemformula}%3.3 own manual Jul-2013
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathrm}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symrm}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl
  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathsf}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symsfup}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl
  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\compound{\ch{\cmathrm{A_{$2x$}B_{$x$-$1$} * $n$ H2O}}: roman h1.}
\newcommand\compoundcap{\ch{\cmathsf{A_{$2x$}B_{$x$-$1$} * $n$ H2O}}: sf h2.}


\begin{document}


{\rmfamily\compound} ; 

{\sffamily\compoundcap}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx 
\end{center}
\caption{\compoundcap}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(acknowledgement: the l3 code is adapted from egreg's solution for transliterating Hittite)

`\ch` loses a space here, somehow, after the `n` of `$n$`. Easy enough to re-insert one. (Edited to add: the reason is that the parser regex step replaces `$n$ H` with `\ensuremath{symsf{n}}H`, so `\ch` never gets the opportunity to add the math space. Oops!)

This method requires the input code to be given twice, once to each parser.

`\newcommand\compound{\ch{\cmathrm{A_{$2x$}B_{$x$-$1$} * $n$ H2O}}: roman h1.}`

and

`\newcommand\compoundcap{\ch{\cmathsf{A_{$2x$}B_{$x$-$1$} * $n$ H2O}}: sf h2.}`

**Method 3**

And widening-up the `$..$` pairs to include the `__` so that the parsed text can be typeset independently of `\ch`,

`\cmathrm{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$  H2O} i2a;`

`\cmathsf{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$  H2O} i2b.`

shows that `\ch` is seeing sf text (blue), rather than sf math (red).

[image: cleaner math markup]

Which is OK, because it is all sf now anyway, and, in turn, the sf in the caption comes out OK.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=blue]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Sans}[range=sfup/{latin,greek,num},Colour=red]

\usepackage{chemformula}%3.3 own manual Jul-2013
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}




\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathrm}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symrm}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl

  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathsf}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symsfup}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl

  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
xxx i2
\end{center}
\caption{\ch{\cmathsf{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$\ H2O}} i2b.}
\end{figure}

Normal text, without \textbackslash ch:

\cmathrm{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$  H2O} i2a;

\cmathsf{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$  H2O} i2b.
\vspace{24pt}

rmfamily and sffamily, with \textbackslash ch:

{\rmfamily\ch{\cmathrm{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$ H2O}} i2a rmf};

{\sffamily\ch{\cmathsf{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$ H2O}} i2b sff}. {\small <= needs a space}




\end{document}
```

**Method 4** (non-working)

Putting the input code into one macro requires one level of appropriate suppression of expansion (or escaped code) to prevent the parsers and `\ch` getting an already tokenized list.

[image: expanding macro]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=blue]
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\setmathfont{Noto Sans}[range=sfup/{latin,greek,num},Colour=red]

%\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}%3.3 own manual Jul-2013
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont={sf,bf},
    textfont={sf},
}

\newcommand\compoundi{A$_{2x}$B$_{x-1}$ * $n$ H2O}
%\edef\compoundia{\meaning\compoundi}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathrm}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symrm}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl

  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathrm_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmathsf}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl { #1 }
  % change every run of anything between $ ...$ into $sym...{}$
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \$([^\$]+)\$ }
   { \c{ensuremath}\cB\{\c{symsfup}\cB\{\1\cE\}\cE\} }
   \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl

  % print the result
  \tl_use:N \l_lyssane_cmathsf_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
%\begin{center}
%xxx f
%\end{center}
%\caption{\ch{\cmathb{$\mathsf{A}_{|2x|}\mathsf{B}_{|x|-|1|}$ * |n| H2O}} f}
%\end{figure}

\compoundi cmpd i -- the macro ; 

{\rmfamily\ch{\compoundi} cmpd i rm -- with \textbackslash ch }; 

{\sffamily\ch{\compoundi} cmpd i sf -- with \textbackslash ch }.

{\rmfamily\ch{\cmathrm{\compoundi}} cmpd i rm cm -- and parser}; 

{\sffamily\ch{\cmathsf{\compoundi}} cmpd i sf cm -- and parser}.

\end{document}
```